# Transfering Image Data with QTCPSocket

Tags: c++, tcp, qt

In my program I am transferring image files continuously through QTCPSocket for each frame I am creating new connection which I believe causes the performance problems. But I couldn't transform my code into single connection one. Everything works fine I can transfer images continuously but frame rate seems lower than I expected. I send 24 frames per second and recieve roughly 13 frames.

How can I improve performance of my code ?

Here is my code:

**tcpsender.cpp**

```
#include "tcpsender.h"
#include "ui_tcpsender.h"
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QtCore>    
#include <QDebug>
#include <QBuffer>

#define XRES 640
#define YRES 480

TCPSender::TCPSender(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TCPSender)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    statusLabel = new QLabel(tr("Ready to send frames on port 6667"));
    statusLabel->setWordWrap(true);
    startButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Start"));
    auto quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Quit"));
    auto buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox;
    buttonBox->addButton(startButton, QDialogButtonBox::ActionRole);
    buttonBox->addButton(quitButton, QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole);

    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(startButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &TCPSender::startConnection);
    connect(quitButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &TCPSender::close);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), SLOT(startSending()));
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &TCPSender::sendFrame);

    auto mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(statusLabel);
    mainLayout->addWidget(buttonBox);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("Broadcast Sender"));
    camera = new Camera("/dev/video0", XRES, YRES);

    time = QTime::currentTime();

}

TCPSender::~TCPSender()
{
    delete ui;
}

void TCPSender::startConnection()
{
    if (socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
    {
        QString ip = ui->lineEdit->text();
        socket->connectToHost(ip, 6667, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    }
    else
    {
        socket->disconnectFromHost();
    }
}

void TCPSender::startSending()
{
    startButton->setEnabled(false);   
    timer.start(1000/24);
}

void TCPSender::sendFrame()
{
    if(socket->state()==QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState){
        auto frame = camera->frame();
        image = new QImage(frame.data,XRES,YRES,QImage::Format_RGB888);
        QImage im = image->convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
        QByteArray ba;
        QBuffer buffer(&ba);
        im.save(&buffer,"BMP");
        socket->write(ba);
        int speed = time.msecsTo(QTime::currentTime());
        time = QTime::currentTime();
        speed = 1000*300/speed;
        ui->label->setText(QString("%1 kb/s").arg(speed));
        delete image;
   }
    startConnection();
}
```

**receiver.cpp**

```
    #include "reciever.h"
#include <QBuffer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>

#define XRES 640
#define YRES 480
#define SIZE 640*480*3

Reciever::Reciever(QObject* parent): QTcpServer(parent)
{
    connect(this, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(addConnection()));
}

void Reciever::addConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket* connection = nextPendingConnection();
    connections.append(connection);
    QBuffer* buffer = new QBuffer(this);
    buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    buffers.insert(connection, buffer);
    connect(connection, SIGNAL(disconnected()), SLOT(removeConnection()));
}

void Reciever::removeConnection()
{
    receiveImage();
    QTcpSocket *socket = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    QBuffer* buffer = buffers.take(socket);
    buffer->close();
    buffer->deleteLater();
    connections.removeAll(socket);
    socket->deleteLater();
}

void Reciever::receiveImage()
{
    QTcpSocket* socket = static_cast<QTcpSocket*>(sender());
    QBuffer* buffer = buffers.value(socket);
    qint64 bytes = buffer->write(socket->readAll());
    emit sendBuffer(buffer,bytes);
}
```